# CakePHP keep session from main domain across to a subdomain

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication

I am working with Cakephp and I have an issue maintaining session across subdomains. My problem is as follows:

- Users login on 'localhost/login'
- If authenticated they are redirected to 'customer.localhost/home'.

Currently Cake is creating a cookie for each domain ie localhost and customer.localhost.
This means that I cannot keep the session working for the user. Is there a way to make all cookies domain fixed to the parent domain with the goal of keeping the session working across subdomains?

I have tried entering this in my bootstrap but it has no effect:
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.localhost');

If you think this cannot be done please feel free to let me  know so that I can move on from this frustrating problem.

Many thanks,

kSeudo

Comment: Which version of CakePHP are you using? 1.3 or 2.x?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Sessions (CakePHP 2.x):**

To make the session cookie valid for all your subdomains and the top level domain, you actually need to set it yourself in your `APP/config/bootstrap.php` file:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com');
```

Then, in your `APP/config/core.php` file, set Security to low:

```
Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');
```

> "otherwise the referer_check  will be set to the current HTTP_HOST in
>   the CakeSession object line 441."

**Sessions (CakePHP 3.x)**

> The session cookie path defaults to app’s base path. To change this
>   you can use the session.cookie_path ini value. For example if you want
>   your session to persist across all subdomains you can do:

```
Configure::write('Session', [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'ini' => [
        'session.cookie_path' => '/',
        'session.cookie_domain' => '.yourdomain.com'
    ]
]);
```

---

---

**Cookies (CakePHP 2.x):**

On [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html) it explains that you can use the 'domain' variable:

> The domain name allowed to access the cookie.
>   e.g. **Use ‘.yourdomain.com’ to allow access from all your subdomains.**

Per their example code:

```
<?php
public $components = array('Cookie');
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Cookie->name = 'baker_id';
    $this->Cookie->time =  3600;  // or '1 hour'
    $this->Cookie->path = '/bakers/preferences/';
    $this->Cookie->domain = 'example.com';
    $this->Cookie->secure = true;  // i.e. only sent if using secure HTTPS
    $this->Cookie->key = 'qSI232qs*&sXOw!';
    $this->Cookie->httpOnly = true;
}
```

**Cookies (CakePHP 3.x):**

[Read here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/cookie.html).

> The domain that the cookie is available. To make the cookie available
>   on all subdomains of example.com set domain to ‘.example.com’.

Comment: Thanks with your help, I eventually got it to work. One thing to remember do not try to do this with 'localhost' make sure you use a domain in your host like 'example.com'.

Comment: i just emptied the variable 'session.cookie_domain' in bootstrap.php for it to work for me in localhost. your answer did give me the hint to solution!!

Comment: @Dave I'm using cakephp v1.3 and i have done all changes as mentioned above it's working  for session but not working for cookie, what can i do for cookie?

Comment: what about if cake version is 3?

Comment: I have multiple projects at same server host on different ports
session getting mixed up, can I specify domain along with port?

Comment: I don't see any option for specifying the port. You could prefix the keys with the port or something like that I suppose. Not secure, but might work depending on what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is a config in app/Config/core.php to change session cookie domain:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'ini' => array(
        'cookie_domain' => '.example.com'
    )
));
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but the accepted answer did.

Comment: This works, but with the right directive name. Answer edited.