# Make session valid with all subdomains

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

How can I make a valid Auth session with all subdomains including www.example.com and http://example.com addresses

Now CakePHP just broke Auth session if one is created on www., and you visit the website without www.! And vice versa.

I can't use redirect to http://www.example.com if users are comming without using www., because there will be a lot of subdomains and redirect becomes not an option.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not at my computer at the moment, but you might be able to override the session domain by adding this to your `app/Config/bootstrap.php`

```
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".example.com");
```

The CakePhp Session doesn't seem to have a configuration option to set this, but the standard php configuration should probably work.

Related questions can be found here;

[CakePHP keep session from main domain across to a subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519570/cakephp-keep-session-from-main-domain-across-to-a-subdomain)

[PHP Sessions across sub domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains)