# Merging Session values?

Tags: php, cakephp, opencart

I am combining OpenCart and CakePHP Modules and I want to use session value of CakePHP in OpenCart session of customer ID.

```
$this->Session->write('customer_id',$id);//in cakephp
$_SESSION['customer_id'];//in open cart
```

Value of `customer_id` comes correct but not shown in session of OpenCart, is there any method to do so?

Comment: Most likely your sessions are completely separate - which probably means that the cookie domain for both sessions is different and/or they are using differently-named session cookies.

Comment: so how do i make a common cookie domain for both of them ??

Comment: Well, by applying how you'd do that to any two applications, to both your CakePHP app and opencart. Possible duplicate of [CakePHP keep session from main domain across to a subdomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519570/cakephp-keep-session-from-main-domain-across-to-a-subdomain)

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP may be creating a multi-dimensional array on $_SESSION. I would do a `print_r($_SESSION);` to see where exactly the customer_id is ending up, or use CakePHP's debug() function `debug($_SESSION);`

Comment: Debugging CakePHP's session data will at most give you CakePHP's session data - [the problem is likely different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761656/merging-session-values#comment47676116_29761656).

Comment: Another way for debugging in CakePHP: `$this->log($variable_name, 'debug');` If you use DebugKit toolbar, simpler than before: `debug($_SESSION)`.